# main.main not defined error when running goapp test

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, go

In my Google App Engine Go project, when I run `goapp test`, I get the following errors:

```
runtime.main_main: main.main: not defined
runtime.main_main: undefined: main.main
```

Since it's a not a normal go app, but a Google App Engine one, it doesn't have a main.main(), so what do I need to do to get the tests running?

Comment: Do you have the `*_test.go` files in the working directory when running `goapp test`?

Comment: The test files were in subfolders, but when I put a dummy test in the working directory it runs the dummy test fine. Put your comment in an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

`goapp test` without any parameters will run unit tests that are in the current / working directory.

So before running tests, navigate to the folder containing the `*_test.go` files, then run `goapp test`.

More about testing can be found here: [Local Unit Testing for Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/localunittesting/)

And of course by running

```
goapp help test
```